# In a TCP connection, does send's length match recv's length up to some limit?

Tags: tcp

I am wondering what happens in a TCP/IP connection when the size passed to `send()` grows.

In a simple TCP/IP connection (default attributes, no errors that TCP/IP did not fix), is it guaranteed that the size passed in `send()` will be the size in `recv()`, perhaps up to some limit? If yes, can this limit be determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the data sent by each send() may not match each recv() as the receiver does not know the size of the message. E.g.: A message of 100 bytes may be sent in 10 chunks or in one single shot of 100 bytes.

As regards your second part of the question, the maximum send buffer size can be determined by a simple call:

int sockbufsize = 0; size = sizeof(int); 
getsockopt(skt, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF,(char *)&sockbufsize, &size);  //skt is the socket descriptor

Comment: Depending on the API you are using send() may not even transmit all the bytes you ask it to, if the API you are using allows send() to transmit less bytes than requested it will usually return the number of bytes it did successfully transmit.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not guaranteed.  TCP is a stream protocol and the socket interface to it only guarantees that the byte stream will be transmitted in the right order and without errors, nothing more. Of course, since it guarantees the correct sending of all data, the total amount of bytes sent will be the total amount of bytes received.